# Check the data has updated at server without requesting every frame of the game

Tags: c#, python, json, rest, web-services

I have a game where I have to get data from the server (through REST WebService with JSON) but the problem is I don't know *when the data will be available on the server*. So, I decided to use such a method that hit Server **after specific time** or **on request on every frame of the game**. But certainly this is not the **right, scale able and efficient approach**. Obviously, **hammering** is not the right choice.

Now my question is that how do I know that data has arrived at server so that I can use this data to run my game. Or how should I direct the back-end team to design the server in an efficient way that it responds efficiently.

**Remember at server side I have Python while client side is C# with unity game-engine.**

Comment: Client is the unity3d application.

Comment: Unity3d a game-engine where you write code in C# or JavaScript

Comment: Sorry i don't know the server details. Maybe its PHP or Rest API

Comment: I don't think server can be a problem. You can answer with any server side technology you know.

Comment: Do REST work in a way that it not return anything until data update on the server? when i request him

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156549/discussion-between-mohammad-faizan-khan-and-mjwills).

Comment: @mjwills its python at server side

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly difficult to provide an answer with little details. TL;DR is that it depends on what game you are developing. However, polling is very inefficient for at least three reasons:

- The former, as you have already pointed out, it is inefficient because you generate additional workload when there is no need
- The latter, because it requires TCP - server-generated updates can be sent using UDP instead, with some pros and cons (like potential loss of packets due to lack of ACK)
- You may get the updates too late, particularly in the case of multiplayer games. Imagine that the last update happened right after the previous poll, and your poll is each 5 seconds. The status could be already stale.

The long and the short of it is that if you are developing a turn-based game, poll could be alright. If you are developing (as the use of Unity3D would suggest) a real-time game, then server-generated updates, ideally using UDP, are in my opinion the way to go.

Hope that helps and good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro! I have updated my question with technology details that are using in this architecture. Is there any way available to get data without requesting on server. I mean the server directly push data into my desktop application which is unity3d player.