# Push data in a desktop application from server without making request

Tags: c#, python, rest, web-services, unity-game-engine

I have a [unity3d](https://unity3d.com) Player(a desktop application) where I need some data from the server. The server code is written in **python** while on client side I am using C#. Now I am searching a way that server directly post/push data to my unity player. IMO! it is not possible to push data to unity player without requesting the server (using [WWW class in unity game-engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)). My question is, can python post data to my client unity player? with something like

```
response = requests.post(client_url, data = request_data, headers = headers)
```

I want to do this because [I want to avoid repetitive calls to server which is not an efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708236/check-the-data-has-updated-at-server-without-requesting-every-frame-of-the-game).

Comment: Could you establish a long connection by `websocket`? Or just establish a tcp connection  to exchange data?

Comment: If your messages are not too long you can probably use SignalR. It has a python client as well as a .Net client.

Comment: @Sraw The code which i have currently is just post data at specfic url as code suggest. I don't know about long connection.  IMO it is a TCP connection.

Comment: @ZoharPeled No it will send JSON object with several fields.

Comment: saq n zohar, it is possible to push data in desktop application withou requesting

Comment: That's exactly what [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) does. It enables you to push messages from the server to the client without having the client create a request every time.

Comment: I think you may need to do more research about network communication. The code showing in your question is exactly tcp connection but is a short connection. It will be closed after every requests and be established again before every requests. So it is very costly to repetitively send information. But if you establish a long connection, you just establish connection once and transform data during a long time and finally close the connection. It won't waste time on connection establishment.

Comment: @Sraw but i have to make a request in order to get data, can directly send the data to my client application? like zhoar told about singalR

Comment: Without at least one request, how could server know when to send data?

Comment: @Sraw So it means one request always require. no matter signalR or what plugin i use.